# How to start and stop a thread using ToggleButton in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-togglebutton

Currently i am developing Prototype of Air quality monitoring device using Arduino. The device integrated with three gas sensors that will send the the data over the HC-05 bluetooth module to my android app. I am able to receive the values in real time and display it on the screen and also save it in the SQL database simultaneously.

The problem that encountered by me is when i am implement a toggle button to capture the data, so users can save the data to the database only if they want. In order to achieve that I have to use a thread for save the data every 5 seconds and planning to start and stop the thread using the toggle button. But my code did not work out, every time I press the toggle button it start saving the data in database but when I stop the toggle button it does not work. The thread just keep on running even though I already turn off the toggle button.

I am very new to JAVA and also Android programming, please help me.

Here my code. (The toggle button and the thread part)

```
 logdata.setChecked(false);
    logdata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Is the ToggleButton on?
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();


            Thread capture = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (!isInterrupted()) {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                    MyLocationListener callgpsclass = new MyLocationListener();

                                    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy / hh:mm:ss a");
                                    String dateString = sdf.format(date);

                                    String capdata_gps = (String) callgpsclass.showGPS.getText();
                                    String capdata_mq135 = (String) showMq135.getText();
                                    String capdata_mq9 = (String) showMq9.getText();
                                    String capdata_dust = (String) showDust.getText();
                                    String capdata_air_quality = (String) showAirQuality.getText();


                                    // Insert a row
                                    dbhlpr.insertReading(
                                            dateString,
                                            capdata_gps,
                                            capdata_mq135,
                                            capdata_mq9,
                                            capdata_dust,
                                            capdata_air_quality
                                    );


                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }


                }
            };



            if (on) {
                capture.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data capture started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            else{
                capture.interrupt();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data capture stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to interrupt a different thread. make the thread global and after that inside the `OnClickListener`, first interrupt the thread if toggle button is off (Make sure you do not create a new thread here). And if the toggle button is on, assign a new thread and start.

Comment: Sorry, you can't simply ask for code. Which part you couldn't do? Search in Google how to do that part? learn one by one.